# Свойства :hover :active в Android style

Tags: android, style, css

Привет. Есть ли в Android что-то подобное `:hover :active(css)`? Как этим пользоваться?

Answer (score 1):

[Селекторы](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/Selector.html). Пишите что-то вроде, к примеру, в res/color/test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- нажата -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- фокус -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- дефолтный цвет -->
</selector>
```

А потом, например, у кнопки в поле textColor подставляете:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:textColor="@color/test" />
```

Comment: @Suvitruf, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: @Expert ♦♦ я вообще как комментарий писал это, кто-то в ответ переделал)